# Writing and solving the Euler-Lagrange equation that makes an integral stationary.

Tags: calculus

Given the integral $I=\int_{x_1}^{x_2} x\sqrt{y'^2 +x^2}dx$ write and solve the Euler-Lagrange equation that minmizes I.

Begin by noting that $F = x\sqrt{y'^2+x^2}$

Now we get the partial derivatives $\frac{\partial F}{\partial y'}$ and $\frac{\partial F}{\partial y}$. We see that

$$\frac{\partial F}{\partial y'} = \frac{xy'}{\sqrt{y'^2+x^2}}$$

and

$$\frac{\partial F}{\partial y} = 0.$$

Now we substitute for  $\frac{\partial F}{\partial y'}$ and $\frac{\partial F}{\partial y}$ in the Euler-Lagrange equation:

$$\frac{d}{dx}\frac{\partial F}{\partial y'} - \frac{\partial F}{\partial{y}} = 0 $$

$$\implies\frac{d}{dx}\frac{xy'}{\sqrt{y'^2+x^2}}=0$$
$$\implies\frac{xy'}{\sqrt{y'^2+x^2}}=c_1$$
$$\implies xy' = c_1\sqrt{y'^2+x^2}$$
$$\implies x^2y'^2 = c_1^2(y'^2+x^2)$$
$$\implies x^2y'^2 - c_1^2y'^2 = c_1^2x^2$$
$$\implies y'^2(x^2 - c_1^2) = c_1^2x^2$$
$$\implies y'^2 = \frac{c_1^2x^2}{x^2 - c_1^2}$$
$$\implies y' = \frac{c_1x2}{\sqrt{x^2 - c_1^2}}$$
$$\implies \frac{d}{dx} y(x) = \frac{c_1x^2}{\sqrt{x^2 - c_1^2}}$$
$$\implies y(x) = c_1\sqrt{x^2-c^2} + c_2$$

Is my logic and math correct? What shape makes the integral stationary?

Comment: What do you mean by "What shape makes the integral stationary?"

Comment: The last implication isn't right.

Comment: @Shakespeare I saw a solution for a similar problem where it was arrived at that $$y = \pm 2c_1\sqrt{x-c_1^2} +c_2$$ it was commented after that that the solution that makes the integral stationary is a parabola.

Comment: @Javier So my method is correct, but I'm simply integrating incorrectly?

Comment: @KevinCarroll, yes. Looks right to me.

Comment: @Javier What about when I square root both sides, should I not include the $\pm$

Comment: I integrated again, but got the same exact answer.

Comment: 1) I think you can absorb that sign with $c_1$, don't you? 2) Wolfram gives me a different solution than yours: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%27%28x%29+%3D+%28cx%5E2%29%2F%28sqrt%28x%5E2-c%5E2%29%29+

Comment: I made a mistake. in the second to last implication, x^2 should be x. Forgot to square it.